# can I write my Login Page redirect code in Session_End?

Tags: asp.net

Can I write my code in the `Session_End` method when my session is timeout and I redirect users to the Login Page?

I am using  **Form Authentication**  method.

Currently I have create a "`CheckSession()`" method and calling on each page...

please suggest...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391784/asp-net-session-expiry-redirect-to-login-page

Answer (score 2):

I've always placed the session check code in a master page for webform projects or, more recently, creating a base controller that has this method.  Either way the goal is not to duplicate that code everywhere for obvious maintenance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can manage this through settings in your `web.config` file without having to use code at all. Just ensure that the duration of your forms authentication cookie and your session are the same length. If your authentication session times out ASP.NET will automatically redirect a user to the login page.

Try:

```
<forms ... timeout="20" slidingExpiration="true" />
```

(`slidingExpiration` is `true` by default but I've specified it here because it must be `true` to replicate the timeout behaviour of sessions in ASP.NET)

and:

```
<sessionState ... timeout="20" />
```